# match whether the given start time and end time entered by the user exists

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to match whether the given start time and end time entered by the user exists between the database start time and end time if it is between the time range then only those record should be shown that exists between the timeframe i have used between clause but it is not working.

Database Values

> start                |         end

```
2019-07-27 17:15:00 2019-07-27 19:15:00
2019-07-27 13:15:00 2019-07-27 14:15:00 
2019-07-27 06:15:00 2019-07-27 10:15:00
```

What i have tried is :

```
$start_time='2019-07-14 18:00:00';
$end_time='2019-07-14 19:00:00';
$start_time = date('H:i:s',strtotime($start_time));
$end_time = date('H:i:s',strtotime($end_time));

$results=$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM schedule_diary WHERE (TIME(start) BETWEEN time("'.$start_time.'") AND time("'.$end_time.'") AND TIME(end) BETWEEN time("'.$start_time.'") AND time("'.$end_time.'"))')->result_array();
```

What result i got is:

when i enter 6:00 PM - 7:00 PM i did'nt get any record but it should return record because there is one row 
with 17:15:00 to 19:15:00, when i enter 6:00 AM to 9:00 PM i get all three rows that is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Please use OR instead of AND in your condition

```
$results=$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM schedule_diary WHERE (TIME(start) BETWEEN time("'.$start_time.'") AND time("'.$end_time.'") OR TIME(end) BETWEEN time("'.$start_time.'") AND time("'.$end_time.'"))')->result_array();
```

Comment: @Jusin J : Thanks for your answer but current scenario is when i enter 5:00 PM - 7:30 PM then i got following rows with schedule
05:15 pm to 07:15 pm but the resulting rows starting range is greater than what i entered i.e. 5:00 PM so it must 
come only when i enter 5:00 P.M. or less that 5:00 P.M.